# arithmetic genus of nonsingular curve of degree d in PP^3

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The arithmetic genus of nonsingular curve C of degree d in PP^3 over an algebraically closed field is less than or equal to 1/2(d-1)(d-2).
I must show it by comparing C with a suitable projection from a point into PP^2. 
How can I prove it?

Comment: How did this problem come up?

Comment: Actually, it looks a lot like homework. 

Comment: It is also done in Hartshorne chapter IV.

Answer (score 6):

$\frac{1}{2}(d-1)(d-2)$ is the genus of a smooth plane curve of degree $d$. If you project from $P^3$ to $P^2$ off a point not contained in $C$ you can always get a plane curve of the same degree with at most nodes as singularities, which is birational to $C$ (hence has the same genus). Each node lowers the genus of the image curve by one w.r.t the formula you give. Hence you have the desired inequality.